# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

In the following code, i am getting error at following step:

```
model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

[[image: ]]

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 3):

The `face` module isn't actually a part of the `opencv` library proper. Rather, [`face` is part](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face) of the `opencv-contrib` library. From [the readme](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md):

> This repository [`opencv-contrib`] is intended for development of so-called "extra" modules, contributed functionality. New modules quite often do not have stable API, and they are not well-tested. Thus, they shouldn't be released as a part of official OpenCV distribution, since the library maintains binary compatibility, and tries to provide decent performance and stability.

`opencv-contrib` needs to be installed separately. As @james pointed out (in a now deleted comment), the current easy way to get the Python version is to just do:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

After you run the above `pip` call, your code should work.

Comment: I had installed it

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
pip uninstall opencv_contrib_python
```

and install again:

```
pip install opencv_contrib_python
```